# Evaluate the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|x-c|f(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|x-c|f(x)dx$ given that the antiderivative of $f(x)$ is $F(x)$.

I tried integrating by parts, but I keep having to evaluate $F$ at $\infty$. Any help or push in the right direction appreciated!

Comment: An additional constraint on $F(x)$ is needed to evaluate the integral. For example, $\lim_{x \to \infty} xF(x)=0$ etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your integral is equal to
$$\lim_{a\to-\infty}\int_a^c (c-x) f(x)\>dx+\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_c^b(x-c)f(x)\>dx\ ,$$
whereby both limits have to exist for convergence of the whole thing. Compute the two finite integrals for your given $f$ and see what happens when $a\to-\infty$, $b\to\infty$.